# LaTeX class for typesetting question paper

Tags: koma-script, exam, article

I came across the "exam" class for typesetting question papers in LaTeX. I have TeXLive 2013 distribution. The distribution provides me `exam.cls` file. But my TeXMaker doesn't recognize it. When I downloaded the `exam.sty` file, I got the output but the subject name and many other fields like the university name are all fixed. I am not able to modify them. What do I do?

Comment: [exam](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) is available in TeXLive as `exam.cls`,it's existence can be verified by `kpsewhich exam.cls`. One does not need exam.sty, Where did you get the `exam.sty` ? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `exam.sty` gets you to two (different) obsolete latex 2.09 “document styles” on ctan.  these are pre-1994 attempts at what `exam.cls` does, and they are probably best ignored.

Comment: further to @texenthusiast’s note, `exam.cls` is also available in `miktex` in a bundle called `exam`